# how to make second development based on levigo

Tags: go, wrapper, leveldb

I made a second development on [levigo](https://github.com/jmhodges/levigo), when I finished it and try to install it on my system with the following command:

```
go install github.com/AndreMouche/levigo/
```

it reports the following error:

```
# github.com/AndreMouche/levigo
/home/fun/software/go/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6c: unknown flag -FVw
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide: OS, OS version, Go version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `go` command probably differs from your go tool chain.
Check if the right version of the `go` tool is in the `PATH` of your shell or try reinstalling go.

The `go` tool calls tools like the compiler (e.g. `6g`) and the linker. If the `go` tool version
does not correspond with the version of these tools, said tools may get called with parameters 
they don't *yet know* or they don't know *anymore*.

Check the version using these commands:

```
$ go version
$ go tool 6g -V
```

They both should report the same version string.

See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/xB93KfsQgY8) and [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/2E1bKHcODBc) for related problems.